# Pretty tables with cumulative count / percentage and group totals using R "tables" package

Tags: r, html-table, tabular, cumulative-sum

I am trying to produce a formatted html table which has columns for frequency, cumulative frequency, column percentage, and cumulative column percentage. The table should also have the data subsetted by a grouping variable, and including a group total.

I can almost achieve this using a combination of dplyr and tidyr, but the output is a dataframe which doesn't look so pretty. I wonder if there is an easier way using the `tables::tabulate` command?

```
# Sample data
dat <- data.frame(
  id = 1:100, 
  group = factor(sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace = TRUE)),
  sessions = factor(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))
)

# dplyr/tidyr solution
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(group, sessions) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  spread(key = group, value = n) %>% 
  mutate(All = rowSums(.[-1])) %>% 
  gather(key = group, value = n, -sessions) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(
    cum_n = cumsum(n),
    p = round(n / sum(n)*100,1),
    cum_p = round(cum_n / sum(n)*100,1),
  ) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  reshape(timevar = "group", idvar = "sessions", direction = "wide")

# As far as I get using tables::tabulate
library(tables)
tabular(
  Factor(sessions, "Sessions") ~ 
    (Heading()*group + 1) * 
    (
      (n = 1) + 
        # (cum_n = ??) +
        Heading("%")*Percent(denom = "col")*Format(digits = 2) 
        # + Heading("cum_%")*??*Format(digits = 2)
      ),
  data = dat
)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do, but if you can create a simple data.frame with all the data you need, you could then transform it into an html table with any CSS you like using [tableHTML](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html).

Comment: @LyzandeR Thank you. I guess I was looking particularly for nested/merged column headings, which your link demonstrates very well.

Comment: Perfect, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `knitr::kable` and `kableExtra`, amazing packages for producing tables. You can also set it up for multiple format outputs, for example using the same code to produce `html` and `latex` for *pdf*.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

dat %>% 
  group_by(group, sessions) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  spread(key = group, value = n) %>% 
  mutate(All = rowSums(.[-1])) %>% 
  gather(key = group, value = n, -sessions) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(
    cum_n = cumsum(n),
    p = round(n / sum(n)*100,1),
    cum_p = round(cum_n / sum(n)*100,1),
  ) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  reshape(timevar = "group", idvar = "sessions", direction = "wide") %>%
  kable("html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for altering me to the excellent capabilities of these packages. One thing that I liked about the tables package was the nesting of column headings - I'm not sure this is possible if the data is presented as a data.frame? Ah, have just found the [vingettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) which how to do this!